# Can I use my PC as a Bluetooth headset for my mobile phone?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have a very good headset and have become quite fond of making all my calls on my PC with Skype. In fact, whenever someone calls my mobile phone, I ask them to call back on my Skype-In number.

My computer has Bluetooth, so I'm wondering: **can I use my PC as a bluetooth headset for my phone?** I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 12):

I just managed to do that on Windows 7 64bit using Broadcom's "Widcomm" Bluetooth stack with versions 6.2 and 6.4. There's also option to dial a phone number using Bluetooth.

[image: device control]

Comment: Is this removed from Windows 10? Can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 4):

Things to try:

1. Depending on the device, you can have the device search the PC for available services. Your device should pickup Audio Gateway or Voice Gateway.
2. Go to My Computer and click My Bluetooth Places. Assuming your phone is paired, double click it and you should see a list of available options that your phone supports.
   Right click on 'HS Voice Gateway on XXXXX' (XXXXX is the Bluetooth name for your phone). Click on 'Connect Audio Gateway'. Make sure you also add your computer to your phone by going into the Settings menu, then Bluetooth, down to Handsfree then select My handsfree then select New handsfree.
3. This article might give you some ideas:
   [Use your computer to receive your mobile phone calls via the hands-free/headset profile using Bluetooth (WM5)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150302151308/http://www.inspectmygadget.com/2007/04/30/use-your-computer-to-receive-your-mobile-phone-calls-via-the-hands-freeheadset-profile-using-bluetooth-wm5)

Comment: Page not found.

Comment: Link replaced from the Internet Archive.

Comment: Thanks. Although article from 2009 is unlikely to help visitors in 2016. Like myself. Android on Windows 7? Never heard of either.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 does not support this out of the box. However, the Broadcomm Widcomm bluetooth stack does. Your device will not have this service enabled by default. To enable it, go to bluetooth devices and select the properties for your device. Under service discovery, select 'Hands-free Audio Gateway' and choose okay. A new driver will be installed and when you double click your Bluetooth device to control it, the window will now show an option: 'Listen to audio from your phone...on this PC's speakers'. You should also be able to connect from your phone to transfer audio.

Comment: I have "Hands-free Audio Gateway", but Broadcomm Wildcomm software does not see my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can out the box, but this really depends on the features available on the [Bluetooth stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_stack) you are currently using.

I have had different results with different stacks and cannot really recommend any over any others. A lot of the custom ones (such as Toshiba or Blue Soleil) do contain A2DP, however I am not sure in what direction.

Sorry, I know this is not a good answer, but I hope it gives you a kick in the right direction of what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bluetooth stack that implements headset profile on PC in that manner.

You can consume headset profile if you have half-decent stack installed, but there is no way of providing that service.

Comment: That is actually wrong. The Widcomm stack has this implemented, and it works just fine! =/

Comment: @Artiom I am quite sure that it was true at the time it was answered (2009). :)

Comment: Oh dear. I've completely missed the date of the post. Sorry ;)

Comment: @Artiom: OK. I've flagged the answer and written a note to the moderators to please delete it, since it's outdated.

Comment: @unforgettableid  Just because an answer is now (possibly) wrong is no reason to delete it, it may well still contain pertinent information, especially for older systems or OSes. The best course is to leave a (friendly) comment stating that it may be out of date and then post a new more correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

My Nokia E51 and Windows 7 supports this.
It does not work properly however with the mike.
Only sounds get transferred not speech to the phone :<

Comment: From anonymous contributor: *> If your pc supports it and you have a mic, you can have everything straight on your pc. My laptop has the homephone connected to my pc so when i get a fax/call, it goes straight to my win notification bar*