# Can I use my laptop's Bluetooth to hit 'redial' on mobile phone?

Tags: windows-7, automation, bluetooth

I am working on building an automated test environment for my job.  right now, I have to go down to the server lab, and hit Redial, and redial, and redial, and redial.

I am wondering: Right now, on my Bluetooth hands-free, if I hit the button twice, it 'redials' and calls the last number called.

can I pair a laptop to a Device Under Test and issue the redial that way?

Is there a software available that mimics a hands-free over bluetooth?

The end goal of this is to place a laptop down in the lab, point a webcam at the DUT so I can see call success/completion, VNC into laptop, watch webcam, hit redial, and possibly hit 'hang up' on virtual hands-free.

hope that makes sense, and I hope that someone is able to help.

Comment: Wouldn't a Wireless WebCam be a more simple solution?

Comment: @kobaltz a wireless webcam doesn't address the issue in that it appears the OP wants to observe the phone (the device under test/DUT) when a redial or a hang up are performed.  I think they're looking for a way to trigger the actions for the DUT; the observation portion seems to be addressed fine with the webcam . . .

Comment: Not a duplicate, but [related question](http://superuser.com/questions/58632/can-i-use-my-pc-as-a-bluetooth-headset-for-my-mobile-phone) regarding pairing a PC using the headset to your phone.  What it sounds like you really need is support for the [Hands-Free Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Headset_Profile_.28HSP.29).

Comment: Hi folks,
it looks like the Hands-Free Profile might be what im looking for.  I was unaware that Windows 7 had 'dial' capabilities build it.

yes as well, I need to observe the DUT as well. as call-failed is a different result than "destination phone rang but no answer".

I'm going to play around with the Hands-Free Profile, see if it can do what i need. (dial, and hang-up), and then either a webcam or ip camera (probably a webcam, as I will have to remote into the test-bench anyway.

Comment: tl:dr, Working for a cellular carrier and need to do 3 weeks of testing in our lab, but the lab is loud and scary and id rather stay in my office and just remote-dial when I have to.