# Can I use my pc as a bluetooth headset with windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, android, bluetooth, headset

This Article worked for me on windows 7 but now That I am using Windows 10 I can't seem to figure out how  to make it work. All Hardware is the same only Windows has changed.

[Can I use my PC as a Bluetooth headset for my mobile phone?](https://superuser.com/questions/58632/can-i-use-my-pc-as-a-bluetooth-headset-for-my-mobile-phone)

I have Managed to make all of the rest of the Bluetooth services work with my android phone. Tether, Dial- up modem, audio to pc, file transfers.

Comment: Microsoft updated windows 10 to support bluetooth A2DP sink connections: https://superuser.com/a/1556100/684761. although there don't seem to be many implementations of it yet (just the one UWP app by Mark Smirnov). Though it does seem that the feature that was in windows 7 is slowly making its way back to 10.